# Inequality regarding the Brownian motion stopping time

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

I try to solve a problem related with my previous post. I believe if I can show following inequality then I am done.

Let $D$ be $a$ bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, let $B_{t}$ be a standard Brownian motion starting at $x \in D,$ and let
$$
T=\inf \left\{t: B_{t} \notin D\right\}
$$
Let $q_{t}=\sup _{x \in D} \mathbb{P}^{x}\{T>t\}$, where superscript means that "starting at  $x$".

By strong Markov property, it is easy to see that $q_{s+t} \leq q_{s} q_{t}$. I try to show there exists constant $c$ such that $q_{s+t} \geq c q_{s} q_{t}$, still by strong Markov property, if I can show: for any $x \in D$, there exist a constant $c_1$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}^{x}\{T>t\}\geq c_1 q_t$$
then I am done. But I have no idea how to show this inequality. Can anyone help? Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the inequality you want doesn't hold. The reason being that it would mean that for fixed $t$, $\mathbb{P}^{x}(T>t)$ is bounded below by some positive constant, independent of $x$. However, intuitively, it is clear that as $x$ tends towards the boundary of our domain $D$, $\mathbb{P}^{x}(T>t)$ tends to $0$.

More precisely, if $x^{*}\in{\partial{D}}$ is regular, then $\mathbb{P}^{x}(T>t)\rightarrow{0}$ as $x\rightarrow{x^{*}}$.